# Obter uma palavra de uma variável que tem mais de uma palavra, com jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Tenho uma arquivo JSON com dados de funcionários, como nome completo, data nascimento, estado civil, cargo, salario. Eu preciso mostrar a través de um filtro segundo o nome ou sobrenome, independente de maiúscula ou minuscula:

Exemplo:

```
[
    {"nome_com":"Juan Carlos Herbas Mota",
         "data_na":"21/01/1988",
         "estado_c":"Casado",
         "cargo":"Gerente",
         "Salario":"8500"
    },
    {"nome_com":"Luis Hernan Dias Pato",
         "data_na":"12/10/1960",
         "estado_c":"Solteiro",
         "cargo":"Contador",
         "Salario":"8500"
    }
]
```

Com código jQuery, preciso mostrar os dados por exemplo do Sr, Herbas

Colocando no formulário no input: "herbas" debe mostrar todos os dados desta pessoa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode iterar o JSON buscando os resultados com `for`, convertendo a string da busca e de onde irá buscar em minúsculas para evitar o *case sensitive*:

```js
var data = [
   {"nome_com":"Juan Carlos Herbas Mota", "data_na":"21/01/1988", "estado_c":"Casado", "cargo":"Gerente", "Salario":"8500" },
   {"nome_com":"Luis Hernan Dias Pato", "data_na":"12/10/1960", "estado_c":"Solteiro", "cargo":"Contador", "Salario":"8500" }
];

function buscar(){
   
   var nome = $("#nome").val().toLowerCase(),
   resultados = '';

   for(var item of data){
      
      if(~item.nome_com.toLowerCase().indexOf(nome)){
         
         for(var dados in item) {
             resultados += dados+": "+item[dados]+"<br>";
         };
         
         $("#resultado").html(resultados);
         break;
         
      }
   
   }
   
   if(!resultados) $("#resultado").text("Nada encontrado");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="nome" value="herbas">
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="buscar()">Buscar</button>
<br>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

O primeiro `for` com `of` pega cada objeto da array. O segundo `for` com `in` pega os valores das *chaves* do objeto (`item[dados]`). Caso não encontre nada, o valor de `resultados` será *false*.

Answer (score 1):

Para complementar a já boa resposta do @dvd, coloco aqui outra solução utilizando [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) e [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) e [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

### Primeira abordagem com `filter` e `indexOf`

Utilizando as duas funções acima citadas para filtrar as pessoas pode fazer:

```
const pessoasFiltradas=pessoas.filter(pessoa=>pessoa.nome_com.indexOf(filtro)!=-1);
```

E só com esta linha de código faz o filtro que precisa. Vamos tentar detalhar o máximo esta linha de código:

- Estamos a dizer que `pessoasFiltradas` corresponde ao execução do método `filter`
- O `filter` que filtra com base na função passada
- No exemplo acima, filtra se o `pessoa.nome_com` contem o texto em `filtro`
- O `indexOf` devolve `-1` se não existir, ou seja se não contiver o texto passado

Note no entanto que não existe qualquer código relativo a maiúsculas e minúsculas logo tem de escrever `Herbas` para funcionar.

Veja e experimente com `Herbas`:

```js
const pessoas = [
    {"nome_com":"Juan Carlos Herbas Mota",
         "data_na":"21/01/1988",
         "estado_c":"Casado",
         "cargo":"Gerente",
         "Salario":"8500"
    },
    {"nome_com":"Luis Hernan Dias Pato",
         "data_na":"12/10/1960",
         "estado_c":"Solteiro",
         "cargo":"Contador",
         "Salario":"8500"
    }
];

const procura = document.getElementById("procura");

document.getElementById("procurar").addEventListener("click", function(){
  let filtro = procura.value;
  const pessoasFiltradas = pessoas.filter(pessoa => pessoa.nome_com.indexOf(filtro) != -1);
  console.log(pessoasFiltradas);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="procura" placeholder="Pessoa a procurar">
<input type="button" id ="procurar" value="Procurar">
```

### Verificando se não existem resultados para a procura

Também se torna simples perceber se não existem pessoas para a procura em causa pois apenas tem que testar se o tamanho do array obtido no `filter` é `0`:

```
const pessoasFiltradas=pessoas.filter(pessoa=>pessoa.nome_com.indexOf(filtro)!=-1);

if (pessoasFiltradas.length > 0){
    console.log(pessoasFiltradas);
}
else {
    console.log("Não existem pessoas para o nome indicado");
}
```

### Pesquisa *case insesitive*

Agora para criar uma pesquisa *case insensitive* precisa de antes de aplicar a pesquisa, converter tanto o filtro como os dados do array para maiúsculas ou minúsculas. Neste exemplo irei converter ambos para minúsculas com base no método [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) da `String`.

Portanto vai ser necessário aplicar `toLowerCase` ao `filtro` e ao `nome_com` a ser testado:

```js
const pessoas = [
    {"nome_com":"Juan Carlos Herbas Mota",
         "data_na":"21/01/1988",
         "estado_c":"Casado",
         "cargo":"Gerente",
         "Salario":"8500"
    },
    {"nome_com":"Luis Hernan Dias Pato",
         "data_na":"12/10/1960",
         "estado_c":"Solteiro",
         "cargo":"Contador",
         "Salario":"8500"
    }
];

const procura = document.getElementById("procura");

document.getElementById("procurar").addEventListener("click", function(){
  let filtro = procura.value.toLowerCase(); //aqui
  const pessoasFiltradas = pessoas.filter(
      pessoa => pessoa.nome_com.toLowerCase().indexOf(filtro) != -1);
      //-----------------------------^ e aqui
  
  if (pessoasFiltradas.length > 0){
    console.log(pessoasFiltradas);
  }
  else {
    console.log("Não existem pessoas para o nome indicado");
  } 
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="procura" placeholder="Pessoa a procurar">
<input type="button" id ="procurar" value="Procurar">
```